# Convert Map of maps into Lists using Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a map:

```
Map<String, Map<Integer, List<Integer>>>
e.g. Map<Name, Map<Id, List<ReferenceId>>>

Outcome:
List<Id>
List<ReferenceId>
```

I wanna convert this map into two list of Integers. One list contains inner-map keys, and other contains inner-map value (i.e. `List<Integer>`)

Can anyone tell me how to do this in Java 8 using streams?

I tried this way but got Cast Exception, can not convert String to Integer.

```
map.values().stream()
    .map(m -> m.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(e -> e.getKey())
    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
    .flatMap(l -> l.stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 17):

```
Map<String, Map<Integer, List<Integer>>> map = ...

List<Integer> keys = map.values()       // Collection<Map<Integer, List<Integer>>>
        .stream()                       // Stream<Map<Integer, List<Integer>>>
        .map(Map::keySet)               // Stream<Set<Integer>>
        .flatMap(Set::stream)           // Stream<Integer>
        .collect(Collectors.toList());  // List<Integer>

List<Integer> values = map.values()     // Collection<Map<Integer, List<Integer>>>
        .stream()                       // Stream<Map<Integer, List<Integer>>>
        .map(Map::values)               // Stream<Collection<List<Integer>>>
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)    // Stream<List<Integer>>
        .flatMap(List::stream)          // Stream<Integer>
        .collect(Collectors.toList());  // List<Integer>
```

Answer (score 7):

There is no way, how your code

```
List<Integer> list = map.values().stream()
    .map(m -> m.entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> e.getKey())
            .collect(Collectors.toList()))
    .flatMap(l -> l.stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

can produce a `ClassCastException`, unless you managed to insert objects of wrong type into the source map via unchecked operation(s) *before* the Stream operation. Such a situation is called *heap pollution* and you should compile your entire code with all warnings enabled (`javac`: use option `-Xlint:unchecked`)  and solve them.

But note that your code is unnecessarily complicated. The chain, `.entrySet().stream().map(e -> e.getKey())` is streaming over the entries and mapping to the keys, so you can stream over the keys in the first place, i.e. `.keySet().stream()`. Then, you are collecting the stream into a `List`, just to invoke `.stream()` in the subequent `flatMap` step, so you can simply use the stream you already have instead:

```
List<Integer> list = map.values().stream()
    .flatMap(m -> m.keySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Alternatively, you can let the collector do all the work:

```
List<Integer> list = map.values().stream()
    .collect(ArrayList::new, (l,m) -> l.addAll(m.keySet()), List::addAll);
```

Getting the values instead of the keys works similar, but requires another `flatMap` step to get the `List` elements:

```
List<Integer> list = map.values().stream()
    .flatMap(m -> m.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

which is equivalent to

```
List<Integer> list = map.values().stream()
    .flatMap(m -> m.values().stream())
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Again, there’s the alternative of letting the collector do all the work:

```
List<Integer> list = map.values().stream()
    .collect(ArrayList::new, (l,m)->m.values().forEach(l::addAll), List::addAll);
```

or

```
List<Integer> list = map.values().stream()
    .collect(ArrayList::new, (l,m)->m.forEach((k,v)->l.addAll(v)), List::addAll);
```

Comment: Nice answer as usual. Am-I right saying that letting the collector do all the work may perform a *little* better since you save one streamification ?

Comment: @Jean-François Savard: this basically boils down to the question, whether the target collection may draw a benefit from using `addAll` rather than repeated `add`, e.g. the `ArrayList` will ensure that the capacity is sufficient for the entire collection. In theory, the `toList` collector could use an intermediate data structure avoiding the cost of capacity increase operations, but today, that doesn’t happen. Similarly, a `flatMap` could allow more concurrency in a parallel stream, but afaik not with the current implementation. So today, doing everything in the collector is likely to win.

Answer (score 3):

If your value is like `Map<String,Object>`. And your `Object` is like `Map<String,Object>`:

```
 Set<String> mapKeys = myMap.entryset()    //Set<Entry<String,Object>>
.stream()                                  //Stream<Entry<String,Object>>
.map(m->(Map<String,Object>) m.getValue()) //Stream<Map<String,Object>>
.map(Map::keySet)                          //Stream<Set<String>>
.flatMap(l->l.stream())                    //Stream<String>
.collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

it works

Answer (score 0):

Adding for one more working scenario

```
 Map<Integer, List<Integer>> existingPacakagesMap = // having value {123=[111, 222, 333], 987=[444, 555, 666]}
```

Retrieving logic

```
 List<Integer>   ListOfAllPacakages= existingPacakagesMap.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Result will be

> ListOfAllPacakages=  [111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666]